# Site URL for AdMob (App published in Getjar.com)

Tags: android, admob

I have developed an Android app which I have published to getjar.com.

Also, I have integrated AdMob into the application. Ads are coming fine in the Emulator. But I am doubtful about the **Site URL** I have provided while registering my app on the AdMob site.

Getjar generated 2 URLs as shown below

GetJar: getjar.com/mobile/165691/NotepadSD
App it! Service at: getjar.com/NotepadSD

I don't know which URL I should put on the AdMob site. I have registered the first one.

I will appreciate if someone could tell me which URL is to be given.

Regards,
Shankar

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but AdMob says that it must be a link like:

> market://app?id=package-name

or something. Not the http:// one. But i don't have a glue where i can get it.